# How show the scrollbar in Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, positioning

I would like to use a scrollbar on a div using the property overflow:auto and setting overflow:hidden on the body. It works well with Chrome but not with Firefox and IE.

Can anyone explain me why there is 2 different behavior with this code?

```
<html lang="en" class="fillScreen" dir="ltr"><head> 
   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template4.css" type="text/css">  

    <style>

        .fillScreen {
            bottom:0px;
            height:100%; 
        } 

         html, body {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden; 
        }


    </style>

  </head> 

  <body class="fillScreen"> 

   <div class="fillScreen" style="display:table;width:100%">

        <div class="fillScreen" style="display:table-row">

            <div style="border: solid 2px red;overflow:auto;display:table-cell;overflow:auto" class="fillScreen" >              

                    <div class="fillScreen" style="display:table;width:100%;overflow:auto">             

                        <div class="fillScreen" style="border: solid 1px blue;" style="display:table-row">              

                            <div class="fillScreen" style="display:table-cell">             
                                <div class="fillScreen" style="position:relative">   

                                    <button width="142px" height="20px" style="position:absolute;top:99px;left:20px;">OK</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>          

                        </div>

                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is possible to test it here http://jsfiddle.net/nMSvv/2/
Scrollbar apears in Chrome when resizing the window.

I add, that I absolutely need to display the button with absolute position and need to keep this structure of div

Thank you for any help

Comment: I dont see any scrollbar when resizing even in chrome

Comment: Same here, Chrome 23 on Windows has no scrollbar like FF.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here : http://jsfiddle.net/nMSvv/3/

I needed to wrap the div where I want a scrollbar with :

```
<div class="fillScreen" style="position:relative;overflow:auto">               
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">

    </div>
</div>
```